# Run method Safe cancellation?

Tags: c#, cancellation

I want to call a function in a different thread than my GUI.

I used the below code to trigger the function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tokensource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokensource.Token;
    Task.Run(()=>foo() , token);
}

private void foo()
{
    // Uses some resources
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

How can I safely close the occupied resources in `foo()` when the task is cancelled?

Comment: How to clean up depends on what those resources actually are and what the implementation of `foo()` is. Neither of these details is present in your question. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: *"when the task is cancelled"* - the task is not auto-magically *canceled* when you call `Cancel` on cancelation token. Each task should receive and process token, this is where you can release all resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the token to the function as well. The cancellation token passed to Task.Run won't abort an already running task, it will prevent a scheduled task from running.

Inside `foo`, you can check the token for cancellation and return, or throw an exception. You can use a `using` block to dispose resources safely. Eg:

```
private void foo(CancellationToken token)
{
    using(var reader=new StreamReader(somePath)
    {
            string line;
            // Read the line if no cancellation was requested
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested && (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
    }
}
```

This code reads a line only if cancellation wasn't requested and returns quietly otherwise

You can also throw an OperationCancelledException by calling [CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested)

```
private void foo(CancellationToken token)
{
    using(var reader=new StreamReader(somePath)
    {
            string line;
            // Read the line if no cancellation was requested
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
    }
}
```

This will throw an exception that will be raised in the calling code when the task's result is retrieved, eg when using `await Task.Run(..)` or `Task.Run(..).Wait()`

Answer (score 1):

Your Method should handle the CancellationToken like that:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    Console.WriteLine("Press CTRL+C to cancel important work");

    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) => {
        eventArgs.Cancel = true;

        tokenSource.Cancel();
    };

    var task = Task.Run(() => foo(tokenSource.Token));

    task.Wait();

    WaitFor(action: "exit");
}

private static void foo(CancellationToken token)
{
    const int Times = 10;

    for (var x = 0; x < Times && token.IsCancellationRequested == false; ++x) {
        Console.WriteLine("Important work");

        Task
            .Delay(200)
            .Wait();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Free resources: {token.IsCancellationRequested}");
}

public static void WaitFor(ConsoleKey consoleKey = ConsoleKey.Escape, string action = "continue")
{
    Console.Write($"Press {consoleKey} to {action} ...");

    var consoleKeyInfo = default(ConsoleKeyInfo);

    do {
        consoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    while (Equals(consoleKeyInfo.Key, consoleKey) == false);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

BR
incureforce

Answer (score 0):

The code you're spinning up in a task should be responsible of taking into account cancellation. And the cancellation token you pass into the "Task.Run" method will be used only to cancel non-started tasks.